# How to update a table column in Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I'm trying to update a column in Mysql using `@PostMapping`.

The entity table has 5 columns

```
customer_id, customer_name, total_amount, amount_paid, amount_debt
```

We provide arguments for `customer_name, total_amount, amount_paid`.

`amount_debt` will be calculated as `amount_total - amount_paid` and written back to `amount_debt` column for each `POST`.

The equivalent SQL seems to be

```
update emi_details 
set amount_debt = amount_total - amount_paid;
```

I tried it, using

```
getAmount_debt() { return amount_total - amount_paid; }
setAmount_debt(Integer amount_debt) { this.amount_debt = amount_total - amount_debt; }
```

methods inside the entity class.

However, in `POST` request it seems, I need to provide the `"amount_debt": 0` argument, otherwise it's not getting written into MySql.

When I tried removing the `get` & `set` methods and did the `minus` inside the constructor, and later `POST` request without `"amount_debt": 0`, it shows `amount_debt` has a value in response, but no value in the `amount_debt` column.

It seems, I may need to write some `@Query` inside the `@PostMapping` before

```
return emiDetailsRepository.save(emiDetails);
```

but I'm not sure about it.

Please guide

Things I tried are as follows:

1. Entity - `EmiDetails.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emi_details")
public class EmiDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer customer_id;
    
    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String customer_name;
    
    @Column(name = "amount_total")
    private Integer amount_total;
    
    @Column(name = "amount_paid")
    private Integer amount_paid;
    
    @Column(name = "amount_debt")
    private Integer amount_debt;;

    public EmiDetails() {}
    
    public EmiDetails(String customer_name, Integer amount_total, Integer amount_paid, Integer amount_debt) {
        super();
        this.customer_name = customer_name;
        this.amount_total = amount_total;
        this.amount_paid = amount_paid;
        this.amount_debt = amount_total - amount_paid;
    }

    public Integer getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_id(Integer customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    public String getCustomer_name() {
        return customer_name;
    }

    public void setCustomer_name(String customer_name) {
        this.customer_name = customer_name;
    }

    public Integer getAmount_total() {
        return amount_total;
    }

    public void setAmount_total(Integer amount_total) {
        this.amount_total = amount_total;
    }

    public Integer getAmount_paid() {
        return amount_paid;
    }

    public void setAmount_paid(Integer amount_paid) {
        this.amount_paid = amount_paid;
    }

    public Integer getAmount_debt() {
        return amount_total - amount_paid;
    }

    public void setAmount_debt(Integer amount_debt) {
        this.amount_debt = amount_total - amount_debt;
    }   
}
```

2. Repository `EmiDetailsRepository.java`

```
public interface EmiDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<EmiDetails, Integer> {}
```

3. Controller - `EmiDetailsContoller.java`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class EmiDetailsContoller {
    @Autowired
    private EmiDetailsRepository emiDetailsRepository;
    
    //get all data
    @GetMapping("/emi_details")
    public List<EmiDetails> getAllEmiDetails() {
        return emiDetailsRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    //post data
    @PostMapping("/emi_details")
    public EmiDetails createEmiRecord(@RequestBody EmiDetails emiDetails) {
        return emiDetailsRepository.save(emiDetails);
    }
}
```

4. POST Request- Writes data in each column

```
{
    "customer_name": "Sandeep Roy",
    "amount_total": 75,
    "amount_paid": 8,
    "amount_debt": 0
}
```

5. POST Request- Writes data but in `amount_debt` column

```
{
  "customer_name": "Sandeep Roy",
  "amount_total": 75,
  "amount_paid": 8,
}
```

Apologies for writing everything on the question itself, haven't tried out Heroku yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Calculate the amount debt inside your `createEmiRecord` method.

Just update your `@PostMapping` method to the below code

```
@PostMapping("/emi_details")
public EmiDetails createEmiRecord(@RequestBody EmiDetails emiDetails) {
    
    //Calculate your debt here using the values in the provided emiDetails
    
    return emiDetailsRepository.save(emiDetails);
}
```

### Long Answer

Start by fixing your Entity class. Entity classes are plain POJOs and should not have any business logic.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emi_details")
public class EmiDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer customer_id;
    
    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String customer_name;
    
    @Column(name = "amount_total")
    private Integer amount_total;
    
    @Column(name = "amount_paid")
    private Integer amount_paid;
    
    @Column(name = "amount_debt")
    private Integer amount_debt;

    .....SETTERS AND GETTERS

}
```

Update your `createEmiRecord` method to the following

```
@PostMapping("/emi_details")
public EmiDetails createEmiRecord(@RequestBody EmiDetails emiDetails) {
    
    //Calculate Amount debt here
    Integer amount_debt = emiDetails.getAmount_total() - emiDetails.getAmount_paid();
    
    emiDetails.setAmount_debt(amount_debt);
    
    return emiDetailsRepository.save(emiDetails);

}
```

Comment: Let me try it out.

Comment: Also fix your `EmiDetails` pojo. In the constructor it says `this.amount_debt = amount_total - amount_paid;` and in the setter `setAmount_debt`, it says `this.amount_debt = amount_total - amount_debt;`.

Comment: Let me know if worked for you. Also accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out, Tried assigning RequestBody object with Enity object's method, but it's being showing error about return type. I understand your answer, but not being able to do it so far. If you can guide a little more, it will be helpful.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: I confirm it's being working now. Thanks for guiding me.